# HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error on Docker

Tags: docker, iis, dockerfile, iis-10

I'm trying to rewrite all my URL's to HTTPS but getting this error, not sure what am I doing wrong:

Config Error

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

web.config:

```
<rewrite>
      <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTPS" />
        <add name="X-FORWARDED-PROTO" />
      </allowedServerVariables>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS_AlwaysOn" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
          <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTPS" value="on" />
          </serverVariables>
          <action type="None" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have also installed Rewrite module and ARR on Docker container

```
# Install Url Rewrite
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi /install/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi
RUN msiexec.exe /i c:\install\rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi /passive

ADD  https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/D/C/ADC4BAF8-A094-47B5-A6F6-CE4C5ED18BF8/ARRv3_setup_amd64_en-us.EXE /install/ARRv3_setup_amd64_en-us.exe
RUN c:\install\ARRv3_setup_amd64_en-us.exe /Q
```

Comment: you could try this rule: <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>

Answer (score 0):

Build a normal IIS 10 machine for testing first and you should notice the same error, as that `allowedServerVariables` cannot be in `web.config`.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#allowed-server-variables-list)

Comment: Sure, seeing the same error. Any idea how do I rewrite all my traffic to HTTPS?

Comment: HTTP to HTTPS rewrite has so many approaches, but I don't think what you used above is one of them.

Comment: If you can suggest any that would be awesome, I’m kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

### To enable SSL Rewrite simply add this inside:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="SSL Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
  </rule>
</rules>
```